# In ability to deleti an object in entity framework 5, which contains a GUID Expected {0xdddddddd, etc}

Tags: winforms, entity-framework

I'm trying to remove an object in entityframework 5 which contains a GUID as the primary key (I use a DGV to display the data from the database). 
No matter what I do, I keep receiving the exception: " Expected {0xdddddddd, etc}.".

What am I doing wrong?

Here is the relevant code:

```
string a = dataGridViewEmployees.CurrentRow.Cells[0].ToString();
Guid empnum = Guid.Parse(a);
Employeee emp2 = ctx.Employeees.First(i => i.EmployeeID==empnum);
ctx.Employeees.Remove(emp2);
ctx.SaveChanges();
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: And which line throws the exception? Did you check the content of `a`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

and if you try:

```
string a = dataGridViewEmployees.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
```